# Session_start function missing in PHP

Tags: php, session

This code explains the my issue in brief. The session_start function doesn't exist in php. It should!

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('session_start'))
            $error = 'error_session_missing';
echo "<h1>$error</h1>";
```

HTML output:

```
<h1>error_session_missing</h1><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD ...cut...
```

I've scoured the net for solutions - all related seem to be geared towards not using session_start correctly, and the php docs have not helped resolve the issue. I have combed php.ini, tried various re-compile options with php5 - but no matter what, this error persists.

What could possibly cause this function not to exist?

Solution:
cd /usr/ports/www/php5-session/ && make install clean

Comment: php version? what happens if you do session_start? undefined function?

Comment: What re-compile options did you try specifically? It's pretty difficult to end up with a PHP interpreter without session support. Only when deliberately using `--disable-session` that is..

Comment: perhaps that helps: [http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=12565](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=12565)

Comment: That does help! The solution is to install port www/php5-extension in addition. Thank you redreggae!!

Comment: i use this code and it's working fine

Comment: Perhaps a phpinfo(); dump would be useful

Comment: @redreggae you should post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just install the php5_session module.

```
cd /usr/ports/www/php5-session
make install clean
```

and restart apache / php process

A bit more on this at http://www.freebsdmadeeasy.com/tutorials/web-server/install-php-5-for-web-hosting.php